# Where should non-template specific helpers be located in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor

I have two template with tables

```
<template name="table1">
  <table>...</table>
</template>
```

and

```
<template name="table2">
  <table>...</table>
</template>
```

I want to populate both template with the same variable but still have them separated in two different templates.

It would be easy to create a helper for a template if I had both tables in the same template as:

```
<template name="bothTables">
  <table>...</table>
  <table>...</table>
</template>
```

I guess I should create a helper for both templates but have the logic to the variable somewhere else. Where should I locate the file with the function that creates the value of the variable which I want to populate to both templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one :

> Defines a helper function which can be used from all templates.
>   http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

Example :

1)    `create a file in client/lib/helpers.js`

2) helper.js

```
Template.registerHelper('globalHelper', function(id) {
   if(Meteor.userId() === id)
     return "Yes";
   else
     return "No";
 });
```

3) In your templates :

```
<template name="table1">
  <table>{{globalHelper '123'}}</table>
</template>

<template name="table2">
  <table>{{globalHelper '123'}}</table>
</template>
```

Option two :

If you want to populate the tables with the same content, you can pass the context of the parent template to the child template for get the data if you want `{{> tableContent _id }}` :

```
    <template name="table1">
      <table>{{> tableContent }}</table>
    </template>
    <template name="table2">
      <table>{{> tableContent }}</table>
    </template>

    <template name="tableContent">
      {{#each listOfData}}
        <tr>
        <td> 
          {{name}}
        </td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </template>
    tableContent.js =>
      Template.tableContent.helpers({
        listOfData: function () {
          return X.find({_id: this._id});
      }
});
```

Option three : 
Register the helper in both templates.

```
<template name="table1">
      <table>{{ listOfData }}</table>
</template>

<template name="table1">
      <table>{{ listOfData }}</table>
</template>

table1.js=>
  var listOfData = function(){
    return ExampleColleciont.find();
  };
  Template.table1.helpers({
    listOfData : listOfData 
  });
  Template.table2.helpers({
    listOfData : listOfData 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But the variable shouldn't be globally accessible. It is a collection selector which is almost the same for both tables, so I guess I should define the selector outside of the helpers so I can reuse the logic in helpers for both the templates.

Comment: Ok register the helper in both template in the same js file, i updated my answer.